# Jq - calculate length of each array in JSON and update it

Tags: arrays, json, select, jq

I have the following JSON array

```
[
  {
    "name": "California",
    "Data": {
      "AB00001": ["Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Sacramento", "Fresno", "San Jose", "Palo Alto"]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Oregon",
    "Data": {
      "CD00002": ["Portland", "Salem", "Hillsboro"]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Washington",
    "Data": {
      "EF00003": ["Seattle", "Tacoma", "Spokane", "Bellevue"]
    }
  }
]
```

With `jq '.[].Data[] | length'` I can get the length of each array, but I need to create `Length` key under `Data` object and assign to it the length of the array which is in the Data object. The result should look like the following:

```
[
    {
        "name": "California",
        "Data": {
            "ID00001": ["Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Sacramento", "Fresno", "San Jose", "Palo Alto"],
            "Length": 6
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Oregon",
        "Data": {
            "ID00002": ["Portland", "Salem", "Hillsboro"],
            "Length": 3
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Washington",
        "Data": {
            "ID00003": ["Seattle", "Tacoma", "Spokane", "Bellevue"],
            "Length": 4
        }
    }
]
```

The problem here is that in my example the object name holding the array (`Data` in my example) and the array name itself (`AB00001/CD00002/EF00003`) are not known in advance. However, the values of the `name` key is known. Also, the array might be empty, so in this case, the `Length` should be 0.

So the algorithm pseudocode should be either of one as I've envisioned:

```
for the whole JSON file, 
if the type is an array, 
then assign it to the Length key created in the parent object of that array, 
next
```

or

```
For the specific value in the name key, select,
if the entry contains an array
create Length key in the array's parent object, 
assign the length of the array,
select the next value of the name key
```

I tried to use with jq's `walk` or `..` for the first approach but didn't work.
What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A solution to the immediate problem (in which .Data is a single-key object with an array-valued key) could be as simple as:

```
map( .Data.Length = (.Data[]|length) )
```

This can be adapted to the more general problem in steps.  First, consider this generalization:

```
map( .Data |= if length==1 and (.[]|type) == "array" 
              then .Length = (.[]|length) 
              else . end )
```

#### Solution

To make the actual solution easier to understand, let's define a helper function:

```
def addLength:
   (first(keys_unsorted[] as $k
          | select(.[$k]|type == "object")
          | .[$k]
          | keys_unsorted[] as $l 
          | select(.[$l]|type == "array")
          | [$k,$l]) // null) as $a
   | if $a 
     then setpath([$a[0],"Length"]; getpath($a)|length)
     else .
     end;
```

A general solution can now be written using `walk`:

```
walk(if type == "object" and has("name")
     then addLength
     else . end)
```

Comment: thanks, your answers are great as usual.
Just one clarifying question - how your solution can be used if I do not know the name of the ``data``?
What is given is that for every ``{}`` construct in the JSON file, there is a key named ``name`` and in the same block, there is an object holding array. 

The name of that object holding the array and the name of the array is not known in advance.

Comment: See update. I was hoping you'd be able to take the final leap yourself :-)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be what you want:

```
jq '.[].Data |= . + { length:.[]|length } ' data.json
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "California",
    "Data": {
      "AB00001": [
        "Los Angeles",
        "San Francisco",
        "Sacramento",
        "Fresno",
        "San Jose",
        "Palo Alto"
      ],
      "length": 6
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Oregon",
    "Data": {
      "CD00002": [
        "Portland",
        "Salem",
        "Hillsboro"
      ],
      "length": 3
    }
  },
 # etc.
```

Comment: Thanks! One question - how your elegant solution can be generalized if the name of the object which holds the array - ``Data`` in this case - is not known?